# How can I export specific data based on filtering from dynamoDB table using CLI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to export a specific dataset where primary key contains a specific string  , from dynamoDB table.
I want to import the same data into another table later.

Can anyone please help me with the query ??

I tried to get the specific data in json format using aws dynamodb scan --scan-filter '{"Name":{"AttributeValueList":[ {"S":"ser"} ], "ComparisonOperator": "CONTAINS"}.

But this data can't be imported to another table later

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the CLI for this? Unless you're an absolute genius with bash scripting I would advise that you create a simple script using any of the SDKs.

You need to first `Scan` with a filter expression and with the results of that you iterate it in a loop and call `PutItem` and write to a second table.

You can also use BatchWriteItems to write data in batches to speed up the process.

This package has plenty of example to help: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples